# Matrix operation difficulty

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am having trouble in pushing back a vector into a matrix. Considering, N×N matrix called `MyMatrix`, where `N = 10` which consists of zero and non-zero elements with the diagonal elements being all zero. There are 2 vectors: `Positive_Vector` of dimension 15 that consists of 10 non-zero elements extracted from `MyMatrix` and `ConceptsVector` consisting of `N` elements respectively. Suppose  the vector consists of the follwing elements
`Positive_Vector = [MyMatrix(1,2), MyMatrix(1,6), MyMatrix(2,5), MyMatrix(2,6), MyMatrix(2,10), MyMatrix(3,1), MyMatrix(4,10), MyMatrix(5,3), MyMatrix(5,9),MyMatrix(6,1),MyMatrix(6,7),MyMatrix(7,3),MyMatrix(7,4),MyMatrix(8,1),MyMatrix(8,3)];`

```
Concepts = [0.6,0.1,0.0,0.2,0.8,0.33,0.21,0.5,0.11];
```

My problem is how can I update `MyMatrix` with a new vector `New_Positive_vector` consisting of the same dimension but different values of the elements, such that the following operation

```
C1  = Concepts*NewMyMatrix
```

can be performed?

This is how I extracted the `Positive_Vector`. Can somebody please show how to do the reverse ie push back the new elements of `New_Positive_Vector` into the the respective places in `NewMyMatrix`?

```
for ii = 1:10
 for jj = 1:10
  if (MyMatrix(ii,jj)~=0)
    Positive_Vector = MyMatrix(ii,jj);
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation is vague but I assume that you want to extract the non-zero (or positive) elements from a matrix, do some operations in these elements, and push back them into the original matrix. Then I suggest,

```
MyMatrix = (rand(5)>0.5).*rand(5);

[n,m,Positive_vector] = find(MyMatrix);
k = sub2ind(size(MyMatrix),n,m);

MyMatrix(k) = Positive_vector*2;
```

First line is for generating a random matrix with some zeros. Second line is to find the non-zero element of the matrix. If you just want the positive element, then you can modify it to `find(MyMatrix > 0)`. Here, n and m are the sets of row and column numbers of non-zero elements, but I make that into a 1D indices in the third line. Fourth line is to apply some operation (this case multiply by 2) to the extracted vector and push back to the original places in the original matrix.

I assume that you do more complicated operation than multiplying the non-zero elements by 2. Otherwise you can do something like this...

```
 MyMatrix = MyMatrix - (MyMatrix>0).*MyMatrix + (MyMatrix>0).*(MyMatrix)*2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is just a slightly simpler way of doing what ysakamoto does:

```
%// some test matrix
MyMatrix = (rand(5)>0.5).*rand(5);

%// Logical indices to the non-zero entries
inds = MyMatrix ~= 0;

%// Do operations on the non-zeros, and assign results back    
MyMatrix(inds) = 2*MyMatrix(inds);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then you should do the following:

First of all, with the code you have provided for generating `PositiveVector`, you will get a single element and not a vector. I assume you want to generate it as follows:

```
[nonZeroRows,nonZeroCols]=find(MyMatrix~=0);
Positive_Vector=MyMatrix(sub2ind(size(MyMatrix),nonZeroRows,nonCols));
```

Suppose now you have a `New_Positive_Vector` which you want to insert into `NewMyMatrix`, you do it as follows:

```
NewMyMatrix=zeros(size(MyMatrix));
NewMyMatrix(sub2ind(size(NewMyMatrix),nonZeroRows,nonZeroCols))=`New_Positive_Vector`;
```

Comment: The values in Positive_Vector are all logical 1's when I did find(MyMatrix~=0). After I deleted ~=0 then the code works fine. Hence, I have accepted the previous answer. Anyways, thank you for your help, the rest of the code snippet is otherwise ok.

Comment: Ok. Learn to use `sub2ind` and `ind2sub`. Those are powerful commands.